# Spring Security 4.X taglib tags are not functioning in jsf 2.X project using XML configuration

Tags: spring-security, jsf-2

I have configured Spring security 4.2.3 in jsf 2.0.1 successfully in a Mavennised project. I also, added Spring security taglib as a dependency but `<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">` is not functioning as expected.

security.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd">
<http auto-config="true"><intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" /><intercept-url pattern="/home" access="permitAll" /><intercept-url pattern="/secured**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" /><intercept-url pattern="/dba**" access="hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')" /><form-login  login-page="/login" username-parameter="ssoId" password-parameter="password" authentication-failure-url="/unsecured" /></http>  <authentication-manager><authentication-provider><user-service><user name="bill"  password="abc123"  authorities="ROLE_USER" /><user name="admin" password="root123" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" /><user name="dba"   password="root123" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_DBA" /></user-service></authentication-provider></authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">  
<context-param> <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>  <param-value>true</param-value>  </context-param>
<context-param><param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name><param-value>client</param-value></context-param>
<context-param><param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name><param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/app*.xml</param-value></context-param>
<context-param><param-name>com.sun.faces.injectionProvider</param-name><param-value>com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider</param-value></context-param>
<listener><listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class></listener>
<context-param><param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name><param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/*.xml</param-value></context-param>
<filter><filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name><filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class></filter>
<filter-mapping><filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name><url-pattern>/*</url-pattern></filter-mapping>
<listener><listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class></listener>
<servlet><servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name><servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class><load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup></servlet>
<servlet-mapping><servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name><url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping><servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name><url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>
<filter><display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name><filter-name>richfaces</filter-name><filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class></filter>
<filter-mapping><filter-name>richfaces</filter-name><servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name><dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher><dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher><dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher></filter-mapping>
<welcome-file-list><welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file></welcome-file-list>  <session-config><session-timeout>-1</session-timeout></session-config>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml dependencies:

```
<!-- START: Spring Security JARS -->
<dependency><groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId><artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId><version>${springsecurity.version}</version></dependency>
<dependency><groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId><artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId><version>${springsecurity.version}</version></dependency>
<dependency><groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId><artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId><version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>dependency>
```

Comment: Please take a look at your post. It is next to unreadable. Please edit it and format it... And your title and second sentence contradict eachother and please improve your post in general as well. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @Stu: still sort of unreadable. And there is nothing JSF related in this question